# Are Compare and Swap/Compare and Set methods an overhead in highly concurrent environment

Tags: java, concurrency

Are Compare and Swap/Compare and Set methods an overhead in  a highly concurrent environment ?

Comment: In a multithreaded environment  if there are different threads trying to change the value using compare and swap.So threads will access data from memory address will compare the current value with current expected value.Obviously If multiple threads try making this operation simultaneously only one thread will succeed and others will fail. But other threads will not block instead invoker can continue with other operation or try the same again with failing threads.Does it create an overhead for retries ?

Comment: The idea behind compare and swap is that it doesn't "really" block (though there are likely cache delays) but instead gives a return code indicating whether the operation needs to be retried.  Clearly if retry must occur that's "overhead", but the scheme is generally considered to be the most efficient synchronization primitive possible on a conventional architecture.

Comment: A key weakness of the CAS operation is its performance in the presence of memory contention.When multiple threads concurrently attempt to apply CAS opera-
tions to the same shared variable, typically at most a single thread will succeed in
changing the shared variable’s value and the CAS operations of all other threads will fail.Significant degradation in performance occurs when variables manipulated by CAS become contention “hot spots”as failed CAS operations generate coherence traffic on most systems,they congest the interconnect and memory devices and slow down successful CAS operations.

Comment: But that problem is present for any scheme which attempts to atomically manage a single storage location in an MP environment.  Having excessive contention on a single shared entity is an application design failure.

Comment: Regarding the last comment, see e.g. the `LongAdder` class introduced in Java 8 for one possible solution to this problem in the context of summing `long` values. Read for example [this](http://minddotout.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/java-8-concurrency-longadder/) and [the Javadoc for `LongAdder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html).